# issue with buttons inside embeddded iframe with IOS 12.2

Tags: ios, iphone, button, iframe

i have an embedded iframe in my web and it was working perfectly until latest IOS 12.2. The buttons inside the iframe are not working anymore, when you press on one of them the iframe scroll up to the top.

Out of the website the iframe works perfect.

Can someone help me?

```
<div class="dmRespCol large-12 medium-12 small-12" style="position:relative;padding-top:100%;overflow:scroll;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;" id="1397547096">
 <iframe src="iframe_url" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" allowfullscreen="0" seamless="" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" id="1432099930">
 </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the scroll so adding a big padding-top and padding-bottom everything work but it still not the best solution because it add a big white space in some devices.